# 'TextView' does not contain a definition for 'setLayoutParams'

Tags: android, xamarin

I would like to add layout param to my TextView.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

but I get an error when I assign this on `myText.setLayoutParams(params);`

It seems like it doesnt recognize `setLayoutParams()`.

I'm using VS2017 xamarin android.

Comment: can you share your error?

Comment: 'TextView' does not contain a definition for 'setLayoutParams' and no accessible extension method 'setLayoutParams' accepting a first argument of type 'TextView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not valid syntax: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Views.View.LayoutParameters/

In Xamarin, you don't use `setLayoutParams()` or `getLayoutParams()`. You use the setter/getter property, LayoutParameters.

Use

```
myText.LayoutParameters = params;
```

Comment: thank you for this :). just saw this 'setLayoutParams()' in some of the articles and got me confused.

Comment: @HarrisQuedado any particular reason you're using Xamarin? Unless this app is also for iOS, you should just be using Android Studio and Java/Kotlin.

Comment: well, i'm trying to learn how to make an android app and picked xamarin in visual studio because i'm much familiar in vs. but eventually for both android/ios :)